# Why does hadoop always looking for java-6-sun

Tags: hadoop, java-7

I cannot find java6 so i try java7 but it does not work.
I try some java6 but it still broke.
Below is when i try to check wherther hadoop is ok.

```
zero@ubuntu:/usr/local/java$ hadoop version
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have to define JAVA_HOME in the `configure` or `hadoop` script.

Comment: This is my JAVA_HOME :   

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this line in your `hadoop-env.sh`?

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

If yes then change it to

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```